# How do you use the results and suggestions from globalsearch in your own View?

Tags: android, search, global, android-searchmanager

Is it possible to call the globalsearch in Android and use the results and suggestions in your own searchbar/resultsrceen (SearchView). This is for a homescreen replacement so I dont't have to search my own data but just everything else on the device. 
Can this be done?